# SSH git clone is forbidden for Bitbucket on Windows

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I am setting up SSH keys to establish SSH connection to my company's private company. But I still cannot clone the repository. I am using Windows 10.

1. I generate the key using the `ssh-keygen` command following the instructions for Windows in this link, https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html.
2. Then I also run following command in Bash command

   ```
   $ eval $(ssh-agent)
   ```
3. I set the private key for the above command

   ```
   ssh-add ~/.ssh/<private_key_file>
   ```

Everything went well. Then I copy the public key `id_rsa.pub` key to the Bitbucket SSH key setting with a label.

When I clone, I am still getting the following error.

```
Cloning into 'my-repo-les'...
ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Network is unreachable
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

In the source tree, I can see all the remote repositories of my organization/ company. But when I clone, I got the following error.

```
Command: git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false ls-remote https://wai-yan-hein@bitbucket.org/lbresearch/frontendplatform.git
Output: 
Error: remote: Forbidden
fatal: unable to access 'https://wai-yan-hein@bitbucket.org/lbresearch/frontendplatform.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Before I had an account set up. I was using it with for Github. Now I set up for Bitbucket. Could that be the issue?

When I run this command, the connection has timed out.

```
ssh -T hg@bitbucket.org
```

Comment: At least part of the problem is a connectivity issue: `ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Network is unreachable` and this timing out `ssh -T hg@bitbucket.org`. Does your DNS setup resolve bitbucket.org? Is ssh/port 22 blocked for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bitbucket also exposes its SSH service on an alternate port, to handle networks (like yours) that block port 22. Try `ssh -Tp443 hg@altssh.bitbucket.org` - that port is typically used for HTTPS, so it's rarely blocked.

If altssh.bitbucket.org:443 returns your username, then you'll need to use a different URL scheme in your clone command: `git clone ssh://git@altssh.bitbucket.org:443/owner/repo.git`

HTTP status 403 is not related to your SSH issues; that status indicates that you're able to reach Bitbucket, and that your credentials are valid, but that you do not have permission to do what you're trying to do.